# Shell script - IFS read syntax error: unexpected redirection

Tags: bash, docker

I have this shell script

```
#/bin/bash
SUB_DOMAIN="test.google.com"
IFS=. read -ra __ <<< "${SUB_DOMAIN}"
IFS=. eval 'DOMAIN="${__[*]:(-2)}"'
echo "${DOMAIN} - ${SUB_DOMAIN}"
```

If I run it under Debian, everything works. But if I start it in a minimal Docker Linux (alpha), I get the following error. Do I have to install anything else there?

```
line 3: syntax error: unexpected redirection
```

Comment: What is the point of that `eval`? And why do you `read` if you later `[*]` it? `minimal Docker Linux (alpha)` There is no "Docker linux (alpha)" that I know of. Could you link what is that "Docker Linux (alpha)"? Do you mean you are running it inside docker virtualization? If so which base image are you running (I do not know of a linux distribution called "alpha")? What bash version if available there? What is your dockerfile or how are you running it inside docker?

Comment: Thank you. I have try it with traefik, but I have also try with other software from docker hub. The comes with the Alpine Linux. At this moment it is version 3.11.6

Comment: Most probably you run your script inside a posix shell as avaliable by default inside [alpine](https://alpinelinux.org/) linux. The `<<<` is a bash extension, available in bash. So then to `Do I have to install anything else there?` yes, actually install bash.

Comment: My goal is actually to separate a string at the points and get the last two values.

Comment: It worked for me in WSL debian.

Comment: @Koda : How did you actually run the script? Also, verify the bash version installed there (by doing a `echo $BASH_VERSION` inside the string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you do not have bash installed and you are running your script in posix shell. The here string `<<<` is a bash extension. And *bash arrays* (and thus expanding `arr[*]`) and `read -a` are also bash extensions.

> Do I have to install anything else there?

Yes, actually install bash and then run your script in bash.

Anyway I suggest knowing the environment you are writing for, do not use specific extensions if you want your script to be portable to environments without `bash` and maybe use a more posix friendly (but I think more resource consuming) alternative:

```
SUB_DOMAIN="test.google.com"
DOMAIN=$(printf "%s\n" "$SUB_DOMAIN" | rev | cut -d. -f-2 | rev)
```

And remember that `eval` is evil - a malicious input like `SUB_DOMAIN="test.$(rm -irf /).com"` may cause havoc on that `eval` line.

Comment: Four sub-shell commands to do the job of the POSIX built-in variable expansion `"${SUB_DOMAIN#*.}"`, maybe it is a bit too much ^^

Answer (score 1):

Do it with POSIX shell grammar and it should be good everywhere:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

SUB_DOMAIN="test.google.com"
DOMAIN="${SUB_DOMAIN#*.}"
echo "${DOMAIN} - ${SUB_DOMAIN}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You said in a comment:

> My goal is actually to separate a string at the points and get the last two values.

The **sed**(1) tool can do this straightforwardly.  If you look at the input string as

```
   text     period  non-periods  period  non-periods  end
foo.bar.baz    .      google        .        com
```

You can translate this into *regular expression* syntax: `.` is any single text character, `\.` is specifically a period, `[^.]` is anything but a period, `x*` is any number of `x`, and `$` is end of string.  Parentheses `\(...\)` (in "classic" regexps) mark a *group* that you'll want to retrieve later.  So you can construct a regexp that matches this string, marking the domain part as a capture group:

```
   text     period  non-periods  period  non-periods  end
    .*         \. \(  [^.]*        \.       [^.]*   \) $
```

Then you can use `sed` to replace strings matching this regexp with `\1`, the contents of the matching group.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
SUB_DOMAIN="test.google.com"
DOMAIN=$(echo "$SUB_DOMAIN" | sed 's/.*\.\([^.]*\.[^.]*\)$/\1/')
echo "$DOMAIN - $SUB_DOMAIN"
```

This will work whenever the POSIX toolset is available, including minimal environments like Alpine containers.  It doesn't depend on any particular shell extensions.